# Reading and Processing a full List of items from the Database with Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

**Problem**

I'm currently using Spring Batch to read data using a `JpaPagingItemReader` to read data by page and then using the same chunk size as page size to process the items.

The problem is that there are a lot of database reads that need to happen during the processing step, which makes this inefficient.

**The Desired Functionality**

Ideally I'd like to read a chunk of data (say 5000 rows), then pass those 5000 rows as a `List` to the processor (not one at a time), for bulk processing.

Then write out the List as normal.

Is this possible? Or is reading from the database always just passed to the processor one by one by one by one?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with MultiResorceReader. It seems that Spring Batch ItemaReaders can only read record by record. Otherweise you need to reimplement read yourself if you want List of objects.